# Parse multi level json in typescript and populate Mat-table in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-material-table

I have got below json in response. Could some please help me to read data from CustNum.
Basically ignore response, ttcust1 and ttcust2 tags from json and parse the rest of the json data.

When I assign whole json output to mat table datasource the value remains blank. Appreciate your help.

```
{
    "response": {
        "ttcust1": {
            "ttcust2": [
                {
                    "CustNum": 1,
                    "Country": "USA",
                    "Name": "Elevation Tours",
                    "Address": "126 East Drive",
                    "Address2": "",
                    "City": "Washington",
                    "State": "DC",
                    "PostalCode": "23646",
                    "Contact": "Tony Stark",
                    "Phone": "(646) 468-3215",
                    "SalesRep": "HXM",
                    "CreditLimit": 456.00,
                    "Balance": 6465.05,
                    "Terms": "Net30",
                    "Discount": 35,
                    "Comments": "This customer is on credit hold.",
                    "Fax": "",
                    "EmailAddress": ""
                },
                {
                    "CustNum": 2,
                    "Country": "Finland",
                    "Name": "John Frisbee",
                    "Address": "Retichinthala 3",
                    "Address2": "",
                    "City": "Karimnagar",
                    "State": "UP",
                    "PostalCode": "21654",
                    "Contact": "David Utten",
                    "Phone": "(156) 215 5461",
                    "SalesRep": "DKP",
                    "CreditLimit": 21654.0,
                    "Balance": 2346.63,
                    "Terms": "Fat30",
                    "Discount": 85,
                    "Comments": "Ship all products.",
                    "Fax": "",
                    "EmailAddress": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable and then filter the dataSource, I did it in the OnInit interface.

```
this.newDataSource = this.dataSource.response.ttcust1.ttcust2
```

Then in the mat-table use the variable newDataSource as datasource

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="newDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Country">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Country}} </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Address">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Address}} </td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

If you have a lot of data in your JSON it may take a while, I suggest you to put a loading spinner if this is the case